# How can I implement a (Trend Bubble)

Tags: graph, processing

I am in need of a tool to show the size of a word according to how many occurrences it has (similar to twitter trending topics),
[image]

is there a software to do this?
if not, is Processing a good option for this?

Thanks a lot

edit, 
tnx for the response!, no I know this is called [tag cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud) and can use the proposed software on the answer and others!, cheers!

I recommend [wordle](http://www.wordle.net/), as it organizes de words in different ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://tagcrowd.com/